# как подключить видео на странице worpress

Tags: wordpress

на странице у меня статикой прописанно видео, но как его можно подключить? я пробовал такое условие прописывать на постер и на видео но не грузит `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>` 
html:

```
<video controls preload="none" class="vd__video" poster="img/poster.svg">
    <source src="/img/video.mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если необходимо вывести путь до папки активной темы, то можно использовать функцию [get_template_directory_uri](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/):

```
<video controls preload="none" class="vd__video" poster="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/poster.svg">
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/video.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Вот в чем вопрос оказывается. А я прочитал его три раза, так и не понял, что значит "подключить", и прошёл мимо))